# Arrival time of French Bee

Tags: international-travel, airport-transfer

i would like to know the departure and arrival of a French Bee Flight BF711 on May 9,2019 from SFO to ORY if that is possible to know

Answer (score 2):

For that specific flight, there is a [FlightAware record of the flight](https://flightaware.com/live/flight/FBU711/history/20190510/0345Z/KSFO/LFPO). (You will need to create an account to see the full historical data.) Here is the relevant info:

[image]